# Can't find class with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having a really frustrating problem with a new project, created with Android Studio. I am getting this error on launch:

```
Unable to instantiate application com.xxx.yyy.communication.ApplicationLoader: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.yyy.communication.ApplicationLoader" on path: /data/app/com.xxx.yyy-1.apk
```

This is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.yyy" >

    <application
        android:name=".communication.ApplicationLoader"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

              ..............

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The class is in the correct package, but it's not found. 
I have tried using the full path, cleaning, rebuild etc.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: are you using proguard ?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

---

The problem was caused by the JDK 1.7 which I was using.
I removed the following lines from the gradle file, and now it works:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```